# How to copy conversations from one team to another with metadata

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-api, clone, microsoft-teams

I want to copy all the posts and replies to another channel with the same sender and keeping all the mentions and metadata. Is it possible to implement the same?

I have tried POST `/groups/{id}/threads` but it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you cannot copy conversations from one team to another team. Could you please raise a [user voice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public-preview/category/182881-developer-platform)?